# Content of string getting messed up when converted from String to stringarray in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a string which is xml data which is very nicely indented and well formed.

```
Dim xmlstring as string
```

I am trying to pass the above mentioned string to a Java Web Service but the input parameter datatype is string array. I am converting the string to string array as shown below

```
localws.receiveNotification("TestQueue", xmlstring.ToString().Split(CChar("")))
```

As the datatype for the input parameter in the above webservice is string() array
for some reason my XML data is getting messed up and lot of elements are breaking and appearing in two lines and my xml data is no more well formed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the string in a string array.. IE:

```
localws.receiveNotification("TestQueue", New String() { xmlstring })
```

Is possible that the service is expecting an array of xml documents or something to that degree?  If so it might each entire xml string that you have as a single element of an array.

Comment: The string accepts just one string array not array of xml docs

Comment: When I said xml documents I was referring to an xml document as a string.  If the definition for the parameter in the service is a string array then chances are it isn't looking to accept a char array.  I would give a shot to wrapping your string in an array (like the example posted) and noting how the service handles processing that.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you, without further information about your string, the service, it's intentions and the definition it will be fairly difficult to help you solve your issue.